# unable to delete emulator/avd from android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I've been running an AVD/emulator via Android Studio which has been working as expected.  However, the emulator/AVD started crashing every time and now it seems to be in a corrupt state. I've tried to delete the AVD via the AS VDM but attempting to do this displays an alert with the following error message:

> AVD Pixel_2_API_29_-_AC5 is already running. If that is not the case,
>   delete the files at
>   C:\Users\asdfg.android\avd/Pixel_2_API_29_-_AC5.avd/*.lock and try
>   again.

When I go to the directory specified in the error message, there's a single directory which ends in ".lock": hardware-qemu.ini.lock

And there's a single file which ends in .lock: multiinstance.lock

Attempting to delete the directory displays an alert modal which states:

> The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is
>   open in another program

Attempting to delete the file displays an alert modal which states:

> The action can't be completed because the file is open in
>   qemu-system-x86_64

Do you ever encounter this type of state where you're unable to delete an AVD via AS VDM and you're not able to delete the specified lock files either?  Have you found a good solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 10):

- Open your `Task Manager` and end `Android Studio`
- Also, end `adb.exe` & `emulator.exe` and `qemu-system-x86_64.exe`
- Go to, `C:\Users\"YOUR_USER"\.android\avd`, here you can find "ini" file and folder for your emulator device. delete both of them.