# AVD Manager: The emulator process for AVD has terminated | Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 | MacOS 12 M1 chip

Tags: android-emulator, x86-64, apple-m1, arm64, android-studio-arctic-fox

The AVD manager is not starting the emulator, whenever tried starting the emulator it shows the below error in screenshot

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because: Do you know the difference in between Apple and Intel?

Comment: yes, that's why I have posted the question and answer so if anyone having similar problem will find it helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to find solution after searching for a while on the internet and posting the answer here so that anyone else facing the same issue could find it easily.

Apple M1 chip has a 64 bit ARM architecture also known as AArch64, so it requires the emulator setup in the following way

When you create a new virtual device select the options shown in the screenshot

[image: Creating new AVD on Apple-M1]

Remember to select the Other images tab and under that verify the ABI is arm64-v8a, then only the emulator will get started.

Here is the screenshot of working emulator
[image: Working AVD Emulator]

Answer (score 1):

I had to free up more storage, and that fixed it for me. I went from <1gb of space to 10+ gb free, and it looks like the emulator process takes no more than 1-2gb.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened with me, and I solved it when I deleted the emulator by opening the task manager and doing the end task for avd, android, and qeum-system and then in this path

> C:\Users*pc*.android\avd

and I

> [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459912/unable-to-delete-emulator-avd-from-android-studio)

-based on this- what was in it from the folder of the emulator and the ini file.
Then i just open android and make new emulator , and work with me then

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try to disable emulator VM acceleration.

You can force the use of the soft x86 emulator by running it from the command line and using the -no-accel option.

i.e. from the SDK/tools directory on Windows :

To list available AVDs:

```
C:\Users\<YOUR_USER_NAME>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator -list-avds
```

To disable VM acceleration:

```
C:\Users\<YOUR_USER_NAME>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_29 -no-accel -no-boot-anim
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#common